# Why does git-sizer say my files are 10 times the size of what my Mac says the entire directory size is?

Tags: git, macos

I cloned the [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) repo and used [git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to run the command `git-sizer --verbose` without making any changes to the repo. I saw that it listed the total size of blobs as 120 MiB. However, when I look at the size of the entire express directory on my mac by right clicking on the express directory in my gui, right clicking and selecting get info it says the entire directory is 10.6 MB and 11.4 MB on disk.

How could this be if the total size of the blobs alone is 10 times that?

Comment: git-sizer is open source and written in go.  clone the repo, [set a breakpoint](https://blog.cloudflare.com/go-has-a-debugger-and-its-awesome), and figure out what it's doing.  That will give you the basis for making a rational comparision, and very possibly answer your question.

Comment: Without knowing precisely what `git-sizer` does it's hard to say for sure, but note that Git stores its internal objects in a compressed—sometimes highly compressed—form, so that `.git` is often smaller than the work-tree.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is if the tool you're using is calculating the full size of each `BLOB` and summing them all up... this could be a useful metric, but would not be reflected in (or reflective of) the disk space actually consumed in your repo.

The `BLOB`s' data may appear in two places on your disk:

For `BLOB`s that are part of the currently-checked-out commit's `TREE`, there is a file in the working directory.  This file *is* what the `BLOB` represents, so its size might be what the sizer utility is reporting; but only files for the current version (not all the historical stuff) are present here.

Every `BLOB` is in the database.  But those are compressed, and may also be reduced to deltas, so the physical space they consume is likely much less than the sum of the sizes of the individual `BLOB`s.